# cannot find where is the syntax error in the code

Tags: php

In this [tutorial](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/) it is explained how to create a RESTful API in PHP.My problem has to do with the code in the section titled **Creating a Concrete API**.I copy/pasted the code in Netbeans and I get a message regarding this code:

```
 $this->User = $User;
```

The message I get from the editor is that the variable $this is unexpected. I cannot find where is the error here.
Thanks.

Here is the code as it appears on the Editor:

```
class MyAPI extends API
{
protected $User;

public function __construct($request, $origin) {
    parent::__construct($request);

    // Abstracted out for example
    $APIKey = new Models\APIKey();
    $User = new Models\User();

    if (!array_key_exists('apiKey', $this->request)) {
        throw new Exception('No API Key provided');
    } else if (!$APIKey->verifyKey($this->request['apiKey'], $origin)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid API Key');
    } else if (array_key_exists('token', $this->request) &&
         !$User->get('token', $this->request['token']))

        throw new Exception('Invalid User Token');
    }

    $this->User = $User;
   }

/**
 * Example of an Endpoint
 */
 protected function example() {
    if ($this->method == 'GET') {
        return "Your name is " . $this->User->name;
    } else {
        return "Only accepts GET requests";
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Add the code before that line, probably you missed a `;` or a `}`. That's why the `$this` is unexpected

Comment: Please post some more code (5–10 lines around the error).

Comment: what code?You mean ; }

Comment: Post the entire code that "you" are using and "how" you're using it. @DimitrisPapageorgiou --- One line of code just doesn't make the cut.

Comment: Your code editor should have picked up on the missing brace. See the new answers given below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu are missing a `{`

```
} else if (array_key_exists('token', $this->request) &&
       !$User->get('token', $this->request['token'])) // HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this` is allowed only when you are inside a class.

You must using `$this` outside the class, hence the error.

Edit :

There is no open brace `{` after

```
else if (array_key_exists('token', $this->request) &&
         !$User->get('token', $this->request['token']))
```

Comment: No, $this is INSIDE the class,so this must not be the source of the error

Comment: I cannot really copy/paste the error massage from the editor since it is baloon window...but here what is says:Unexpexted variable $this after }

Answer (score 0):

Replace this, You have not properly close the `else if` condition  in `_construct` function

```
            public function __construct($request, $origin) {
                parent::__construct($request);

                // Abstracted out for example
                $APIKey = new Models\APIKey();
                $User = new Models\User();

                if (!array_key_exists('apiKey', $this->request)) {
                    throw new Exception('No API Key provided');
                } else if (!$APIKey->verifyKey($this->request['apiKey'], $origin)) {
                    throw new Exception('Invalid API Key');
                } else if (array_key_exists('token', $this->request) && !$User->get('token', $this->request['token'])){         
                    throw new Exception('Invalid User Token');                      
                }

            $this->User = $User;
        }
```